# Lambda S3 getObject - Access Denied - serverless framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I'm encountering a permissions issue in a Node.js serverless Lambda handler which performs `getObject` and `putObject` to resize an image.

The actual bucket name for my project has been replaced with the text `my-bucket-name` in this SO question.

I've verified the IAM role several times in the AWS web console and here is the relevant serverless yml and handler code:

serverless `iamRoleStatements` block:

```
- Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - "s3:ListBucket"
  Resource:
    - "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
- Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - "s3:GetObject"
    - "s3:PutObject"
  Resource:
    - "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
```

serverless `functions` block:

```
createThumbnailImage:
  name: custom-photo-thumbnail
  handler: path/to/src/handlers.createThumbnailImage
  events:
    - s3:
        bucket: my-bucket-name
        event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
        existing: true
```

lambda handler (portions snipped):

```
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner'

const CONST_MY_BUCKET_NAME = `my-bucket-name`;

const s3client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

const fetchSignedS3Url = async key => {
  let params = {
    Bucket: CONST_MY_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
  };
  let command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
  let url = await getSignedUrl(s3client, command, { expiresIn: 24 * 60 * 60 })
  return url
}

// ...snip...

async createThumbnailImage(event, context) {
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  this.logger.log(`bucket=`, bucket, `key=`, key);
  const parsed = path.parse(key);
  const newKey = `${parsed.dir}/${parsed.name}.thumbnail${parsed.ext}`;

  // SIGNED URL not working inside Lambda -- but pasting URL in browser locally works. WTF?
  // const signed_url = await fetchSignedS3Url(key);
  // this.logger.log(`signed_url=`, signed_url);
  // const response = await require('phin')(signed_url);
  // this.logger.log(`response body=`, response.body.toString().slice(0, 200));

  // Access Denied encountered at next line:
  const getObjectResponse = await s3client.send(new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: CONST_MY_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
  }));
  // this.logger.log(`getObjectResponse.Body=`, getObjectResponse.Body.toString().slice(0, 200));

  // ...snip...
}
```

Finally, here is a screenshot verifying the S3 permissions from the AWS web console for the Lambda:

[Screenshot of Lambda IAM role permissions for S3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DASd9.png)

When performing the `GetObjectCommand` above using the version 3 `@aws-sdk/client-s3` SDK, I encounter the error `Access Denied`.

Possibly useful info: If I generate a pre-signed URL to get the object in the Lambda (as in commented code section above), the following works and does not work:

1.) Performing an HTTP request for the resource in the Lambda using the Node.js library `phin` results in an `Access Denied` response.

2.) Copying and pasting the same exact signed URL into Chrome browser incognito on my local machine fetches the S3 object successfully in a browser tab.

Comment: How is `s3client` created?

Comment: Also, noticed you pass a key. If the Lambda has the required IAM permissions to access the bucket in `CONST_MY_BUCKET_NAME` a key should not be needed.

Comment: @GarethMcCumskey I added the code initializing `s3client` above. The `Key` parameter is the location of the s3 object.